# How to pose Dirichlet and Neumann BCs on same boundary?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

Let' s look on the Laplace equation in a rectangle area:

```
Eq0 = Inactive[Laplacian][u[x, y], {x, y}]
\[CapitalOmega] = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}]
```

and try to solve it with various pairs of Dirichlet an Newman BCs on horizontal boundaries:

```
BCD0 = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, y == 0]
BCD1 = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, y == 1]
BCN0 = NeumannValue[1, y == 0]
BCN1 = NeumannValue[1, y == 1]
```

NDSolve yields reasonable solution when the Dirichlet and Neumann BCs are posed on different edges of the rectangle. For example:

```
u1 = NDSolveValue[{Eq0 == BCN1, BCD0}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
ContourPlot[u1[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
  , PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

However it fails if the BCs are set on same edge:

```
u2 = NDSolveValue[{Eq0 == BCN0, BCD0}, 
  u, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
ContourPlot[u2[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
  , PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Nevertheless it is obvious that solution exists and is equal to u[x_,y_]=y.

**My Question is: Is it possible to set 2 BCs on same edge of the rectangle?**

Comment: I think no you cannot for an elliptic second order equation as yours. It does not make sense mathematically, or does it?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher To be precise, initial value problem of Laplace equation is a well-known ill-posed problem, a possible reference: http://www.math.nsc.ru/LBRT/u2/Survey%20paper.pdf

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: My example is a simplified version of my larger post [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244473/numerically-solving-2-nonlinear-pdes-of-2nd-and-1st-order], where $u$ stands for square of the radius $r2[\psi,\chi]$ of a magnetic field line (which is equal to zero at the axis of axial symmetry $\psi==0$), and $\partial_\psi r2[\psi,\chi]=2/B_0[\chi]$ at $\psi=0$, where $B_0$ is the magnetic field on the axis.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Another example of the problem where BCs both for $\psi(r,z)$ and $\partial_r\psi(r,z)$ are posed on the system axis $r=0$ is the Laplace equation in cylindrical system of coordinates for the magnetic potential $\psi$ such that $\vec{B}=\nabla\psi$.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov: I'm somewhat puzzled about your last comment; could you elaborate on it? Where is the outer boundary located? Are there any boundary conditions imposed at that location?

Comment: I mean that no BC should be set on y=1, and 2 BC on y=0, namely u[x,0]==0 and Derivative[u][0,1][x,0]==1.